# Why does my program only work with the debug build?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have a project that has the `main` method accessing another method from another source file, `BigDog(int)`. I'm pretty sure the code is right but CodeBlocks seems to not be able to detect the definition of the method unless I build the other file using debug build in CodeBlocks. In Release, I get the following error when building:

> Error: undefined reference to 'BigDog(int)'

Why is that so?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void BigDog(int KibblesCount);

int main()
{
   BigDog(3);
   return 0;
}
```

mystuff.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 void BigDog(int KibblesCount)
 {
     cout << KibblesCount;
 }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. Somehow you're building it wrong, maybe you release version project isn't set up correctly. Hard to tell at this distance.

Comment: Might help if you quoted the exact error message you get when you try a release build.

Comment: Wild guess: Are you building both object files with the same compiler/toolchain?

Comment: Error: undefined reference to 'BigDog(int)'

Comment: @errandstudy Well that means that when you do a release build you aren't compiling and/or linking mystuff.cpp. In other words your project is set up wrongly to do release builds. I guess you only added mystuff.cpp to the debug portion of your project.

Comment: Try and get out of the habit of `using namespace std`. That prefix is there for a reason: To protect you from naming collisions and to make it clear where those functions, data structures and other things come from.

Comment: Looks fine. Not the way I would do it, but it should build. What environment are you on?

Comment: Wait, nvm. Codeblocks is an IDE. Got you. Maybe you could tell us other things about your debug build configuration?

Comment: Can you try to build the project from terminal?

Comment: where is the include for `mystuff.h`?

Comment: @Henri Menke  how do you know if you're building the object files with the same compiler?

Comment: @Chipster how could you tell the debug configuration?

Comment: @RickPat, there is no indication that he has such a header file.

Comment: @Sid True, i did see the declaration of `BigDog` in `main.cpp` now. This should work.

Comment: @errandstudy It would probably be under settings. I'm in way over my head now, though. Maybe someone else should take it from here. I'd imagine it's a setting of some kind, though.

Comment: @errandstudy As i remember, when you add a new file to codeblocks you can choose to add it to your builds. Try deleting the file and creating it again.

Comment: Thank you all for the information! I think the problem is that whenever I have to create a new file I have to check both the debug and release build whenever I'm adding a new source file to the project. I'm just confused on why I need to check those options. Is this normal for you all?

Comment: @errandstudy Not really. eclipse is more comfortable in this respect. If you place a file into a source folder, it is automatically build with all configurations and you need to explicitly remove the source from build if you don't want to compile it.

Comment: change to `cout << KibblesCount << endl;` and try again

Comment: Please provide the command line used to build the project in both Debug builds and Release builds. I'll retract the down vote and close vote if you provide the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're adding a new file in codeblocks, make sure to check the checkmarks in the dialog to add it to both the debug and the release build.

Also its better practice to move your declarations to a header file and include that where needed, like this:

main.cpp:

```
#include "mystuff.h"

int main()
{
    BigDog(3);
    return 0;
}
```

mystuff.h:

```
#pragma once

void BigDog(int KibblesCount);
```

mystuff.cpp:

```
#include "mystuff.h"

#include <iostream>

void BigDog(int KibblesCount)
{
    // add a newline so the line gets printed immediately
    std::cout << KibblesCount << "\n"; 
}
```